# what happens if two private IP addresses have the same virtual port number

Tags: ip-address

If there are several computers on the local network and it so happens that two of them send a request with the same virtual port number,

How is it determined which request belongs to which computer if their private IP addresses become one public IP address and they have the same virtual port numbers.

For example
192.168.0.2:5555 and 192.168.0.3:5555?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iirc, the gateway router translates between private IP+Port combination and an external port number for its single public IP.

There are different methods of choosing when a port can be addressed externally and when a new port is opened. Check out https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4787#section-4 for specifics.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding ...
for example
there are two private IP addresses and the same virtual port number
192.168.0.2:5555
192.168.0.3:5555 .

On the router using NAT, both the ip address and port number are changed
124,231,54,100: 4867
124.231.54.100: 6165 ,

but when the response comes, the router sees different port numbers but still the virtual port numbers (which the operating system gave on each computer) remains the same.

How does the router know which host the response belongs to?

Comment: It keeps a mapping of external port to the combination of host+port, not just port-to-port. e.g. incoming request on port 4867 goes to 192.168.0.2:5555; request to 6165 goes to 192.168.0.3:5555

Comment: I updated the answer a bit and added reference